Azure - What service(s) do I need to use to make a public dns zone resolve to private zone?

I've set up a hub and spoke topology with peering enabled. The hub contains a basic Azure Firewall.
I've created an Azure Container App in a custom spoke vnet with ingress limited to the vnet only.
I've created a private DNS zone with the container app environment's default domain and static ip

At this point, I can create a VM in the hub vnet and access the container app successfully - the page content is returned via wget.
What I'd like to do now is create a public DNS zone (several actually), that can be used to access the container app via the internet, with all traffic going via the hub firewall, however I'm not sure what else I need to add to make the public zone record ultimately resolve to the private zone record
Will I able to achieve this with the current infrastructure, or do I need to add something extra?
Any advice appreciated.
Thanks
